# Table only sorts first character

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and currently stuck.
When I try to sort a column in my table it will do so by looking at the first character instead of the whole value.
For example: `16, 4, 12, 1, 8` will sort to: `1, 12, 16, 4, 8` instead of: `1, 4, 8, 12, 16`

Also there are text valuables in there. Those too need to be able to sort.

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance

```
const table = document.querySelector("#myTable");
const tableHeaders = table.querySelectorAll("th");

tableHeaders.forEach((header) => {
  header.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const column = header.cellIndex;
    const order = header.getAttribute("data-sort");
    const rows = Array.from(table.rows).slice(1);

    const sortedRows = rows.sort((a, b) => {
      const aCellValue = a.cells[column].textContent.trim();
      const bCellValue = b.cells[column].textContent.trim();
      if (order === "asc") {
        return aCellValue.localeCompare(bCellValue);
      } else {
        return bCellValue.localeCompare(aCellValue);
      }
    });

    table.tBodies[0].append(...sortedRows);

    // Update sort arrow
    tableHeaders.forEach((header) => {
      header.removeAttribute("data-sort");
    });

    if (order === "asc") {
      header.setAttribute("data-sort", "desc");
      header.innerHTML += " &#8910;";
    } else {
      header.setAttribute("data-sort", "asc");
      header.innerHTML += " &#8911;";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It's not just looking at the first character. That's why `12` is before `16`. The problem is that you're sorting as strings, not as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting the values as strings that's why it behaves like that. To sort the values of a column as numbers, you can

- Add something like `data-type="number"` to the header of that column.
- Check if the sort type is a number when a header is clicked.
- Then you sort the values as numbers.

Working Example

```js
const table = document.querySelector("#myTable");
const tableHeaders = table.querySelectorAll("th");

tableHeaders.forEach((header) => {
  header.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const column = header.cellIndex;
    const order = header.getAttribute("data-sort");
    const type = header.getAttribute("data-type");
    const rows = Array.from(table.rows).slice(1);

    const sortedRows = rows.sort((a, b) => {
      let aCellValue = a.cells[column].textContent.trim();
      let bCellValue = b.cells[column].textContent.trim();

      if (type === "number") {
        aCellValue = parseFloat(aCellValue);
        bCellValue = parseFloat(bCellValue);

        if (order === "asc") {
          return aCellValue - bCellValue;
        } else {
          return bCellValue - aCellValue;
        }
      } else {
        if (order === "asc") {
          return aCellValue.localeCompare(bCellValue);
        } else {
          return bCellValue.localeCompare(aCellValue);
        }
      }
    });

    table.tBodies[0].append(...sortedRows);

    // Update sort arrow
    tableHeaders.forEach((header) => {
      header.removeAttribute("data-sort");
      const span = header.querySelector('span');
      if (span) span.remove();
    });

    if (order === "asc") {
      header.setAttribute("data-sort", "desc");
      header.innerHTML += " <span>&#8910;</span>";
    } else {
      header.setAttribute("data-sort", "asc");
      header.innerHTML += " <span>&#8911;</span>";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th data-type="number">Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>63</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```